# Prevent changing columns in SQLite with a trigger only works if PK not provided

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to prevent any user or program to change specific columns in my SQLite database. What I wanted to do is simply create a trigger for update statements where I could keep the old values in for the data set.

An small example table and trigger would look like this:

```
create table testtable
(
    id INTEGER   PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   -- column shouldn't be unchabgeable
    col1  INTEGER   default 0   not null,
    col2  TEXT(10)  default ' ' not null,        -- column shouldn't be unchangeable
    col3  TEXT(30)  default ' ' not null         -- column shouldn't be unchangeable
);

create trigger testtable_trigger
after update on testtable for each row
begin
    update testtable
        set id    = old.id,                      -- set the old values
            col2  = old.col2,
            col3  = old.col3
        where id = old.id;
end;
```

I am using `after update` trigger here because `before update` didn't work at all.

A example dataset

```
insert into testtable (col1, col2, col3) values(42, "a", "b")
```

Whenever I now try to modify `col3` with a update statement this works. `col2` keeps it's initial (default) value. 
Same works for an update statement where `col2` and `col3` are to be modified - they keep their values. And if `col1`, `col2` and `col3` are given only `col1` is actually changed just as I want it to.

```
update testtable set col3 = 'changed' where id = 1;                                  -- nothing changed
update testtable set col2 = 'changed', col3 = 'changed' where id = 1;                -- nothing changed
update testtable set col1 = 1234, col2 = 'changed', col3 = 'changed' where id = 1;   -- col1 changed
```

My problem here is now. to any update statement the PK `id` is given all data is changed. No matter what. It seems that in this case the trigger is not executed. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

```
update testtable set id = 23, col2 = 'changed', col3 = 'changed' where id = 1;    -- everything changed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the ID is changed from 1 to 23, you have to restore it with an UPDATE statement like this:

```
UPDATE testtable
SET id = 1
WHERE id = 23;
```

In other words, the ID value to compare against in the WHERE clause must be `new.id`.

(This will blow up when [recursive triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_recursive_triggers) are enabled.)

---

To actually prevent the change, instead of silently reverting it, raise an error from the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtable_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF id, col2, col3 ON testtable
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "these columns are read only");
END;
```

Comment: Thank you. This was a rather easy fix. I don't undertand why this would cause problems with recursive triggers. Do you care to elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: The trigger is called whenever an UPDATE statement for `testtable` is executed. So the trigger will try to revert its own change, infinitely.